# the keyboard hide my footer when i click on the textarea

Tags: android, html, css, typescript, ionic-framework

[enter link description here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4HCWzbHHkLk&ab_channel=TarikTahoune)

I am coding a chat app with ionic 5 and typescript but, when I open the keyboard the footer is hidden as you can see on the video, And I don't know what am i supposed to change
i tried a lot of things but i didn't fix it yet

there is my code :

```
   <ion-header>
         ...
        </ion-header>
        
        <ion-content class="messages-container" #content class="ion-padding">
        
         
        
       ...
        
        
        </ion-content>
    
<ion-footer>
  <ion-toolbar color="light">
    <ion-row class="ion-align-items-center">
      <ion-col size="10">
        <ion-textarea placeholder="Votre message" autoGrow="true" class="message-input" rows="1" maxLength="500"
          [(ngModel)]="newMsg">
        </ion-textarea>

      </ion-col>
      <ion-col size="2">
        <ion-button expand="block" fill="clear" color="primary" [disabled]="newMsg === ''" class="msg-btn"
          (click)="addChatMessage()">
          <ion-icon name="send" slot="icon-only"></ion-icon>
        </ion-button>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-footer>
```

and the css part

```
.message-input {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid var(--ion-color-medium);
  border-radius: 41px;
  background: #fff;
  resize: none;
  margin-top: 0px;
  --padding-start: 9px;
}

.message {
  padding: 10px !important;
  border-radius: 10px !important;
  margin-bottom: 4px !important;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}

.my-message {
  --background: #af18dd;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: right;
  margin-left: 100px;
  padding: 10px !important;
  border-radius: 10px !important;
  margin-bottom: 4px !important;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}

.other-message {
  --background: #18ddc3;
  color: #fff;
  margin-right: 100px;
  padding: 10px !important;
  border-radius: 10px !important;
  margin-bottom: 4px !important;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}


.time {
  color: #dfdfdf;
  float: right;
  font-size: small;
}
.messages-container {
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
img {
  border: 0;
  width: 16%;
  border-radius: 30px;
}
```

thank you in advance ;)

Comment: Are you using `FullScreen` mode?

Comment: no why ? should i use it?

Comment: No, Dont use it. In ionic `FullScreen` mode causes this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine i have checked it in my device, now if you use statusbar overlay true then you need to remove that code from your component.

If you use capacitor then remove below code.

```
StatusBar.setOverlaysWebView({
  overlay: true //make this overlay:false and try again
});
```

and if you use cordova then edit below line

```
this.statusBar.overlaysWebView(true); //remove this line or make it false
```

### Or

Make statusbar overlay false by preference in 'config.xml' file

```
    <preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false" />
```

Statusbar overlay true would hard code your device screen to full screen so where ever we open keyboard it will not adjust screen size dynamically.

Comment: @123 , please check my edited answer which will help you in cordova as well the issue is on statusbar overlay so if you remove it then it will work perfectly.

Comment: do you have another solution

Comment: i found something. it can help but it s not real good , i put in my config.xml this :

Comment: <preference name="resizeOnFullScreen" value="true" />

Comment: but now my app is on full screen